# Changing the URL ID/Handle of an ArcGIS Online Web App

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, url, entityhandle

My organization has created a series of web apps in ArcGIS Online (using Software as a Service). We plan to create a series of regularly scheduled products, and we want the URLs to be more intuitive. For example:

Rather than:

```
https://organization.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=6647cf0dd0a959
```

We would want:

```
https://organization.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=Product22DEC2016
```

Notice the updated "id=" value.

I have tried updating the URL in both the general settings in ArcGIS Online (below):
[image]
I have also gone into https://ago-assistant.esri.com/ to update the URL.

Both methods just change the reference, and cause (essentially) a 404 error where the product can no longer be found.

Is there a way to actually alter the URL Handle or the ArcGIS Online App ID?

Comment: I dont understand. You want to change the backend ID? The ID that ArcGIS assigns? If thats the case, no, you cant change that. Thats managed by the system.

Comment: Correct, the default ID assigned by the system.

Comment: If you host it on your own server you can change the URL. What I do is, configure the WebApp, download the contents, then move the folder into the wwwroot folder on the server. The URL ends up being https://<servername>/<foldername>

Comment: The only thing I could think to do is basically write a front end service that takes a URL + id (of your choosing) and map that to the arcgis.com item. Basically hide the arcgis.com id with your own url re-director (think bit.ly)

Comment: @KHibma That would be possible with an extra step. I could even just make a basic html page with my ideal URL and embed the webmap.

Comment: @Maksim a possibility, but my organization is still a ways off from ArcGIS for Server. Once we get that capability, your option will certainly be a solution.